# How to ensure record procee by only one pod with springboot and postgres sql

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, locking, atomic

I am using Springboot with postgres sql DB
my springboot aplication having scheduler, app runs with 3 replicas
How do i ensure sheduler from each pod will not process same record

I Know in mongodb there is findAndModify atomic operation provide by mongoOperation interface
is there anythin similer or workaround while using postgres.